# How to deploy a Vue.js App + Django Database to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, heroku

I created a Vue.js App with a Django Database. The Vue.js App is running with router and webpack-bundle. I want to deploy that App to Heroku, so I can access it from there. When I separately deploy them to Heroku it works, but not together in one combined app. My folder structure looks like that:

```
core/
├─ views.py
├─ __init__.py
frontend/
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ index.html
├─ src/
│  ├─ views/
│  ├─ App.vue
│  ├─ main.js
│  ├─ router.js
├─ .gitignore
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
├─ vue.config.js
├─ webpack-stats.json
my-app-products/
├─ api/
├─ admin.py
├─ apps.py
├─ models.py
├─ views.py
my-app-shop/
├─ asgi.py
├─ settings.py
├─ urls.py
├─ wsgi.py
├─ __init__.py
```

The main problem I encounter is, that the vue app is in a subdirectory and I don't know how to deploy two apps in Heroku. If that is even possible, to deploy two apps in one project.

I have knowledge on using git and on changing the heroku buildpack.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to deploy docker containers, since I think is really difficult to run a Front end app and a Back end separately,

Comment: Interesting. I don't know much about docker containers, so do you have a good source, maybe with instructions, where I can take a look.

Comment: Really I don't manage it that well, It's just a suggestion cause I've seen that often the best option for apps that have separate front end and back end, is to manage all in docker containers